# Add a child field for each Product Field - Symfony Forms

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4, symfony-forms

I'm trying to build a Order functionality with Symfony 4.4 Forms

I have this, so far

```
class OrderProductForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('customer', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'App\Entity\Customers',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'label' =>'order_form.name'
            ])
            ->add('products', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => ProductQuantityType::class,
                'label' => '',
            ])
            ->getForm();

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'App\Entity\Order',
        ));
    }
}
```

**and**

```
class ProductQuantityType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('products', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'App\Entity\Products',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'label' =>''
            ])
            ->add('qty', IntegerType::class, [
                'label' =>'order_form.qty'
            ])
            ->getForm();

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => null,
        ));
    }

}
```

That won't render Product Quantity because it has no data. Symfony manual does not say how to do it ... [CollectionType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)

What I really want is to add a Quantity Field for each product and at the same time to add as many products as I want.

This is the doctrine structure

Only the relevant code is included

```
class Order
{
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Customers::class, inversedBy="orders")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $customer;
}
```

```
class Customers
{
   /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Order::class, mappedBy="customer", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $orders;
}
```

Any thoughts on how I can move forward with this ?
Thanks !

Comment: Don't use `'multiple' => true`, as that won't allow you to specify a quantity for each product. See if this [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61298222#61300006) is of any help.

Comment: it doesn't really help, because I want to be able to add multiple products in one Order

Comment: That's what `CollectionType` is for, each entry will be a a product and its quantity.

Comment: I want each product with It's quantity field, and to be able to list all products on a single form